# JQuery selector works perfect, except with Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, undefined, undefined-reference

I want to fetch an URL-Attribute from a div and my code works perfectly find, except on Safari, where this line:

```
var url = $('.image').css('background-image').split('url("')[1].split('")')[0];
```

throws an Error, because the .split-function cannot be executed on an undefined object. Can somebody explain me why Safari does not like this code?

Comment: The value of the background-image is a link to an s3 file and looks like this: url("...Link Attribute..."). So, I gotta get rid of the url("") part^^

Comment: Please show a full example of what the `div` would look like.

Comment: `<div class="image" style="background-image: url("....")"></div>`

Comment: Ok, well if you really do have it quoted the way you've shown it, you have a problem with nested double quotes. The `url` needs to have single quotes around it.

Comment: Well, sorry for the confusion, I added this here to show how the div would work. The link is set within the JQuery code and I use single quotes there `$('.image').css('background-image', 'url(' + data.link + ')');`

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if you just saved `data.link` somewhere else for future reference instead of re-parsing the style?

Comment: Have you tried looking at what Safari returns when you call `$('.image').css('background-image');`? It might be returning something you weren't expecting and causing issues with your calls to split.

Comment: Yes, I just did. Turns out that Safari removes the double quotes automatically. Thank you and sorry for wasting your time^^

Comment: It's not a waste of time if you learned something. Don't forget to mark your questioned answered :)

Comment: Thank you, I will do that, when the two day period is over. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I figured it out. When you call `$('.image').css('background-color')` on a browser that is not Safari, you get the following string:

```
url("http://www.image.com/image1.jpg")
```

When you call `$('.image').css('background-color')` using Safari, the following string is returned:

```
url(http://www.image.com/image1.jpg)
```

Comment: I was working on [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L7j7ke56/1/) of an example solution before you found your answer, figure it might still be helpful